# Querying posts from same categories / tags

Tags: wordpress, post, optimization, tags, categories

I want to find all posts from same categories and same tags like a specific post in a plugin. So I do it actually separately by querying for tags and categories:

```
            $taxonomy_arr = wp_get_post_tags( $this->post->ID, array( "fields" => "ids" ) );
            add_filter( 'posts_where', array( $this, 'additional_filter' ) );

            foreach ( $taxonomy_arr as $tag_id ) {  
                $posts_arr = get_posts( array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => $this->max_results,
                    'tag_id'    => (int) $tag_id,
                    'post_type' => array( $this->included_post_types ),
                    'orderby' => 'rand',
                    'suppress_filters' => false
                 ) );

                 // add to categories selection
                if ( is_array( $posts_arr ) ) {
                    foreach ( $posts_arr as $post_obj ) {
                        if ( is_object( $post_obj ) ) {
                            $local_taxonomy_selection[] = (int) $post_obj->ID;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   

            // get post categories
            $category_array = get_the_category( $this->post->ID );
            foreach ( $category_array as $category ) {  
                $posts_arr = get_posts( array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => $this->max_results*2,
                    'category'    => $category->cat_ID,
                    'post_type'   => array( $this->included_post_types ),
                    'orderby' => 'rand',
                    'suppress_filters' => false
                 ));

                 // add to categories selection
                if ( is_array( $posts_arr ) ) {
                    foreach ( $posts_arr as $post_obj ) {
                        if ( is_object( $post_obj ) ) {
                            $local_category_selection[] = (int) $post_obj->ID;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
// combine post id's arrays
$all_posts = $local_taxonomy_selection + $local_category_selection;
```

It's working but is there a way to do it in one query?

Comment: There is a way to do it all in one query. Give us the table layout in a nice format, let us know what exactly you want, and we'll lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question already has answer on wordpress.stackexchange. So copying same code here.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/how-to-query-posts-by-category-and-tag

```
global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
        'category__and' => 'category', 
        'tag__in' => 'post_tag', //must use tag id for this field
        'posts_per_page' => -1

$posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
  //do stuff 
     endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine but my example above contains an "or" relation between category and tag, not "and". It's like select posts by category or by tag. Is it possible to put it in?